# How to set up laravel 5 with facebook

Tags: php, facebook, oauth, laravel-5

How to set up login with facebook with Laravel 5 I installed php-sdk-v4 and tried something like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use FacebookHelper;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

class LoginFacebookController extends Controller {
        private $helper;
        public function  _construct(){
            FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(Config::get('facebook.app_id'), Config::get('facebook.app_secret'));
            $this-> helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper(url('login/fb/callback'));

        }

        public function getUrlLogin(){

            return $this -> helper->getLoginUrl(Config::get('facebook.app_scope'));
        }

    public function login(){

            return Redirect::to(self::getUrlLogin());
        }



        public function callback(){

            dd(Input::all());
        }
}
```

But get this error:

FatalErrorException in LoginFacebookController.php line 23:
Call to a member function getLoginUrl() on a non-object

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 5 introduces the first-party [Socialite](https://github.com/laravel/socialite) package which includes support for Facebook. [The documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#social-authentication) has more information on how to set it up but in the end, the code required to interact with Facebook is much easier:

```
$user = Socialize::with('facebook')->user();
```

Comment: get this error: Class 'Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider' not found

Comment: Did you include the package with Composer? See [the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#social-authentication) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands:

```
apt-get install php5-curl
composer update
```

Then, add the class in your providers and the `Socialite` alias in your aliases.